# Click to button in webbrowser component using C#

Tags: c#, twebbrowser

I'am using component `webbrowser`. It's possible to click on button on web page?

For example: i have open site `www.google.com` how can I click to start finding?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I really like [the WatiN interface](http://watin.org/), it's fairly simple and nice (: